# Get raw samples in array from iphone library song

Tags: arrays, audio, fft, avaudioplayer

This questions has been asked many times, however I have not found a sufficient answer. I am trying to extract PCM data from a song off the users iPod library then put it into an array so that I can run FFT on it. I can grab any song off the iPod with MediaPlayer framework and obtain its URL. I have converted it into an AVURLAsset and experimented with many AVFramework tools with no luck.

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = [appMusicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
NSURL * assetURL_ = [currentItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL_ options:nil];
```

From this point I need to put its data into an array from which I can run the FFT on the song.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter APIs to read in a compressed file from a URL, and write out raw samples or a WAV/RIFF file, which is just raw samples with a small header of known size (usually 44 bytes) that can be skipped before analysis.  e.g. Use different audio formats for reading and writing if needed.

Once you get a file as raw samples, the app can just read it in as NSData to get at the raw bytes (an audio 16-bit sample will be 2 bytes, which you can get at by casting the C pointer to the bytes).

Comment: While it is often true that wave files are 16 bit and have 44 byte headers, it is by no means always true.

Comment: True.  But that header length is what the current AVAssetwriter creates for 16-bit WAV/RIFF files.